# do-if loop in fortran misbehaving in truncating harmonic series

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Find the smallest number of elements needed for which a harmonic is series sums to greater than the integer m.

I tried this code, but it always gives i=1, how am I supposed to tackle this, if this program is completely wrong, then what program will give me the required number of terms of the series. I have added the output at the end. Please Help.

```
program Harmonic
implicit none
integer :: i,m
double precision :: sum
sum=0.0

Print *, "What is the series limit M??"
Read (*,*) m


  do  i=1,i  

     sum= sum+1.0/i 
     print *, sum

     if ( sum>m ) exit             
  end do

 print *, "The harmonic series with", i,"elements is greater than", m


end program Harmonic
```

Output:

```
What is the series limit M??
10

The harmonic series with  1 elements is greater than 10
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It gives an error (Arithmetic Overflow) Still I don't understand how this will improve my result

Comment: Obviously, start with something smaller and test what it does and increase continuously. What it does is that it will make the program to do something, because otherwise the program is undefined. Very likely `i` now is 0 (any random value is possible though) and so the loop does not do anything, because it is effectively for `i` from 1 to 0.

Comment: Please bare in mind that `1.0/i` is different from `1.0D0/i`. The first is computed in precision `REAL` while the second is `DOUBLE PRECISION`. You need the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `i` has not been initialized. Also the loop "do i=1,1" can give you problems. To use a "do while" should be more clear.

```
program Harmonic
  implicit none
  double precision :: i,m,sum

  i = 0.
  sum = 0.

  print *, "What is the series limit M??"
  read (*,*) m

  do while ( sum < m )
     i = i + 1
     sum = sum + 1./i 
     ! print *, sum
  end do

  print *, "The harmonic series with", i,"elements is greater than", m

end program Harmonic
```

Comment: This harmonic series diverges in real life. But due to lack of precision (even with double precision) computers do not get very far. I ask students to see how far it goes in my scientific programming class. For that, use an 'infinite' do loop (no iterator) and exit when the sum no longer changes. You should have a float() around the i. sum = sum + 1./float(i).

Comment: @DanSp., why should one write `1./float(i)` rather than `1./i`?  Especially when the expression is a double precision one.

Comment: @francescalus. Its a formality to get used to. There are many formulas that have calculations such as: (i-1)/i * (more stuff.....). Without the float(i) or the 1.d0, Fortran will see the first operation in parenthesis as all integer and will do integer arithmetic for the whole equation. You will get the wrong answer when this happens.

Comment: @DanSP., in this answer `1.` is real and `i` is double precision.  There's little point blindly following a formality when this, as with your suggestion, reduces precision.  Even with `i` integer, explicit casting is unnecessary.  As for "integer arithmetic for the whole equation" I expect my compilers to follow the rules of Fortran.

Comment: @francescalus. Ah, i is an integer in original post. Did not notice it as double precision in this answer post. As for formalities, in my experience, it is a bad idea to get used to Fortran doing the conversion for you. If not, you will forget when i is an integer and you try this: `i = 2` and then `answer = (i-1)/i * 42.d0`. Fortran does i-1 / i as integer division because it has not seen any real numbers yet and you get zero.